# Auto fill and submit forms on external site

Tags: php, ajax, curl, bots

I was wondering how does one auto fill multiple forms (using `bot/local server`) on multiple pages of external site (PHP) using ajax or curl.

For example a site `www.abc.com/index.php` has a form `<form> <input name='text'></form>` which takes you to the `www.abc.com/fst.php` when the form is submitted and there is another form on `www.abc.com/fst.php` that needs to be filled and submitted too. I want to automatically fill both form from my local server. How do i accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to using something like greasemonkey ( https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/ ), but the better solution is to use the firebug 'net' tab to capture the post sent when you fill out the form and repeat that post with CURL ( http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php )

```
function post($url,$data) { 
    $process = curl_init($url); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent); 
    if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file); 
    if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
    if ($this->proxy) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    $return = curl_exec($process); 
    curl_close($process); 
    return $return; 
}
```